# flutter ListView builder is rebuilding her widgets every time the list changed

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I am implementing a discussion screen that contain a list of messages so I used A listview.
the list of ListView ih handled with bloc so when a message is added the bloc emit new list that contain the old messages and the new message.
here is my ListView widget

```
BlocBuilder<DiscussionBloc,
                  DiscussionState>(
                              buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
                                   previous.messages != current.messages,
                                    builder: (context, newState) {
                                      return ListView.builder(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.h),
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        reverse: true,
                                        itemCount: newState.hasReachedMax
                                            ? newState.messages.length
                                            : newState.messages.length + 1,
                                        itemBuilder: (builder, index) =>
                                            _buildMessageBubble(
                                                context,
                                                index,
                                                widget.state.messages,
                                                widget.state.conversation,
                                                widget.state.message,
                                                widget.state.isMessageLoading),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
```

when a message is added I emit the state like this
`emit(state.copyWith(messages: [event.message, ...state.messages ]));`

i found that when I add the new message to the head of list the old messages index changed so the list view rebuild their child and when I emit this list
`[...state.messages, event.message]`
the problem don't occurs.
In my case I have to add the message in head of list.

is therea solution to prevent the listView from being reinitialized there widgets every time the list of messages changed ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the == operator on Messages class.

```
@override
  bool operator ==(other) {
    // compare this to other
  }
```

You can use this package for ease.
[Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable)

Comment: i didn't understant the solution that you give can you explain more in order to implement it correctly 
the message model extends Equatable class but I didn't overrde operator method
here is the code for message model [link](https://pastebin.com/qnxSCvhw)

Comment: Dont worry, please place attributes in 'props', that define equality of two objects . Equatable will internally handle == operation.

Comment: i aldready put the attributes in props,